# How do I stop multiprocessing from spamming on exit?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm certain this is really easy, but I can't find a question about it.

I have a bunch of processes running in a pool; when `ctrl+c` is pressed, I want the program to stop and exit cleanly without spamming the screen with "None" for each process closed.

Given the following test code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import multiprocessing
import signal

def graceful_close(blah, blah2):
    exit()
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, graceful_close)

def wait():
    while True:
        pass
try:
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(20)
    for i in range(1, 20):
        pool.apply_async(wait)
    while True:
        pass
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    exit()
```

How do I prevent the output:

```
[-2019-09-15 21:56:06 ~/git/locane $> ./test_mp_exit_spam.py
^CNone
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
[-2019-09-15 21:56:11 ~/git/locane $>
```

What is even causing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `sys.exit` instead of `exit`.

[exit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#exit) is a helper for the interactive shell - [sys.exit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit) is intended for use in programs.

And since you are already handling `SIGNINT`, not sure why the need to handle `KeyboardInterrupt` explicitly

```
import sys
import multiprocessing
import signal

def graceful_close(blah, blah2):
    sys.exit()

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, graceful_close)

def wait():
    while True:
        pass

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(20)
for i in range(1, 20):
    pool.apply_async(wait)

while True:
    pass
```

Comment: I knew it was something stupid, thank you.  I was handling both because I was troubleshooting how to stop the spam.